# mvc3 not all code path returns a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Thanks for reading this.

When compiling got this error:

'ASP.Helpers.Message.DisplayMessage(string, string)': not all code path returns a value

I have a helper class in App_Code\Helpers\Message.cshtml and this is the content so far:

```
@functions{
 public static string DislayMessage(string x, string y)
  {
    IF ((x == "yes") && (y == "yes"))
     {
       return ("something");
     }
  }
}
```

in another page it's being called like this:

```
@{Helpers.Message.DisplayMessage("yes", "yes")}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to return something if the condition is false.  You might want to return null or something at the end of the function, so as to return something in all cases.

```
public static string DislayMessage(string x, string y)
{
    IF ((x == "yes") && (y == "yes"))
    {
        return ("something");
    }

    // fallback case
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because your method is returning something **only if your  IF conditions are true** and you mentioned that your function will return a string (**your return type**). You should better add something to return always.

```
public static string DislayMessage(string x, string y)
{
    If ((x == "yes") && (y == "yes"))
     {
       return "something";
     }
     return "";
 }
```

Comment: hope you will indulge a quick question.. 

when stepping through the code this line:

    @{Helpers.Message.DisplayMessage("yes", "yes")}

Comment: hope you will indulge a quick question.. 

when stepping through the code this line:

    @{Helpers.Message.DisplayMessage("yes", "yes")}

returns 'something'

however; it doesn't appear after the HTML is rendered.

For example:

<form method="post" action="">
<h2>Result is: @{Helpers.Message.DisplayMessage("yes", "yes")} </h2>

//other stuffs go here ....

</form>

any ideas?

Thanks again.